# How do I reference Bamboo artifacts in inline script?

Tags: scripting, bamboo

I want to run an inline script task at the end of my Bamboo build to copy some artifacts to a network share. How do I reference the artifacts output directory in this script please?

Windows Environment if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to [configure Artifact Sharing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO40/Configuring+artifact+sharing+between+jobs) to download the artifact into your workspace. Once its on the file system, you can treat it like any other file using the script task.

Comment: Thanks ... "just tried it" a few minutes after posting but leaving question here for all that follow :)